# Por que não posso armazenar o valor '4294967295' em um inteiro de 4 bytes?

Tags: c, inteiros

Gostaria de saber porque não consigo armazenar o valor '4294967295' em um `int` de 4 bytes sendo que o valor citado convertido em binario dá exatamente 4 bytes (ou 32 bits)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Porque ele não cabe no `int`. O `int` possui tanto números positivos quanto números negativos.  Por conta disso ele vai até 2147483647, justamente porque vai de -2147483648 até 2147483647.

Observe que tanto o `uint32` quanto o `int32` possuem 4 bytes e também possuem 4294967296 números possíveis. A diferença é que um começa do zero e o outro não, você será capaz de usar o 4294967295 se usar o `uint`. Isso ocorre porque um dos bits será usado como um dado qualquer, ao invés de um sinal. O `int` utiliza um bit como sinal, enquanto 1 é negativo, por exemplo.